# plot having different color for different year - R

Tags: r, matrix, plot

How to have the same color for each year using the following matrix (for example, three lines that I have for 1011, I want to have all in red). I have tried 
`plot(All[,1:2],col=1:4)` which gives different color for each point in the plot. Any idea how to solve it?

Appreciate!

```
structure(c(1564.7, 1310.72727272727, 1063.46153846154, 1164.77777777778, 
1284.52941176471, 868.214285714286, 2610.83333333333, 929.47619047619, 
1121.2, 3130.6, 2110.77272727273, 3600.54545454545, 2096.96296296296, 
1688.91666666667, 1371.03846153846, 12610.4, 14047.6363636364, 
11548.2857142857, 14474.3333333333, 16720.9411764706, 15759.5714285714, 
18197.4166666667, 9571.80952380952, 6553, 11778.4, 11159.2727272727, 
12094.2727272727, 11003, 8450.25, 9756.46153846154, 15.6, 17.5454545454545, 
13.7142857142857, 15.1111111111111, 17.4705882352941, 16.3571428571429, 
19.4166666666667, 13.0952380952381, 10.4, 17.8, 16.6363636363636, 
18, 15.8888888888889, 11.25, 13.1538461538462, 1011, 1011, 1011, 
1112, 1112, 1112, 1112, 1213, 1213, 1213, 1213, 1314, 1314, 1314, 
1314), .Dim = c(15L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("NumAct", 
"TR", "Gr", "Year")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Year` values can be accessed using `All[,4]` and passing that as `col` argument will give you a color based on the values of that column.

```r
plot(All[,1:2],col=All[,4])
```

## output

[image: test_out]

## Update

To add legend, you can do the following (I can explain if you want one):

```r
legend("topleft", legend=names(table(ALL[,4])), pch=1, col=unique(names(table(ALL[,4]))))
```

## Output - 2

[image: output_update]

Comment: Thanks @deepseefan. How Can I add a legend to the plot that shows which color is  corresponding to a year? for example, 1011 is read,etc.

Answer (score 0):

For adding legend you can use the following code though it is a manual one but works fine

## Plotting

```
plot(All[,1:2],col=c("coral4","springgreen4","magenta","black"),pch=19)
```

## Add a legend

```
legend(locator(1),legend=c("1011","1112","1213","1314"),col=c("coral4","springgreen4","magenta","black"),pch=19,bty="n",cex=c(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8))
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VrBk.png]

Comment: Probably there will be more year factors in the data set,  than `c("1011","1112","1213","1314")`.

Comment: Whatever data you have provided contains only 4 years. If the years are more you can add it within `c( )` for both `col` and `legend`